# Проблемное деление чисел

Tags: php

Необходимо спарсить участников из группы ВК. В результате не могу продумать логику приложения. Есть опереденное кол-во участников (например **11111**) и используя структуру ссылок вк для перехода по страницам, где отображаются эти самые участники, например offset=кол-во(**минимальное значение 0 - максимальное кол-во участников**).Так вот решил использовать подстановку значений.Тоесть как и сам вк решил брать по 50 на страницу (это максимум). **Для того чтобы перейти на вторую нужно добавить ещё 50. И так дальше.** 
**Сам цикл я реализовал так - делил количество участников на 50 и получал сколько раз нужно выполнить.** Но в результате не выводилось то,что не делилось на 50(я так понимаю).

Вот небольшой кусок кода:

```
$kolvo = 11121;
$res = $kolvo / 50;
echo "$res <br>";
$i = 0;
$link = 0;
 while ($i <= $res) {
  echo "$i =members&offset=$link <br>"
  $link+=50;
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: что вам нужно? сделать `$res` на единицу болше если есть остаток?

Comment: Так точно......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
$kolvo = 11121;
$res = ceil($kolvo / 50);
echo "$res <br>";
$i = 0;
 while ($i <= $res) {
  $link = $i * 50;
  echo "$i =members&offset=$link <br>"
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Работает. Но проблему полностью не решило.Подумал сам решил, спасибо!